# Dispatch Action right after state variable is set

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an initial redux state like this:

```
{
  loggedInUserId: null,
  comments: []
}
```

Here's how my React App looks like:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.getLoggedInUserId();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/comments" component={Comments} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

In my App, I dispatch an action `getLoggedInUserId()` which asynchronously fills the `loggedInUserId` in the state.

The HomePage is a dumb component showing some text. I start the app (route is now '/'), see the HomePage component, then I navigate to the Comments page, which has:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchComments(this.props.loggedInUserId); // Dispatch action to do API call to fetch user's comments
}

render() {
  // Show this.props.comments nicely formatted
}
```

Everything works, I see the list of comments in the Comments component.

But if I refresh the page on the route `/comments`, then by the time the Comments runs componentWillMount, the loggedInUserId has not been loaded yet, so it will call `fetchComments(null)`.

Right now, to fix this, I'm doing in my Comments component:

```
componentWillMount() {
  if (!this.props.loggedInUserId) return;
  this.props.fetchComments(this.props.loggedInUserId);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (!this.props.loggedInUserId && nextProps.loggedInUserId) {
    nextProps.fetchComments(nextProps.loggedInUserId);
  }
}
```

which works well. But I'm doing this in 10+ components, and it seems like a lot of work which can be factorized, but I didn't find an elegant way to do it.

So I'm asking you how do you generally deal with this kind of situation? Any idea is welcome:

- HOC
- side-effects
- other libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using wrapper around `Route`, which checks if users are logged in and if not, redirect them to login page. Wrapped routes are rendered only after userId of authenticated user is fetched.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import URLSearchParams from 'url-search-params'

class AuthRoute extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.isLoading) {
      this.props.getLoggedInUserId()
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.isLoading) {
      // first request is fired to fetch authenticated user
      return null // or spinner
    } else if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      // user is authenticated
      return <Route {...this.props} />
    } else {
      // invalid user or authentication expired
      // redirect to login page and remember original location
      const search = new URLSearchParams({
        next: this.props.location.pathname,
      })
      const next =
        this.props.location.pathname !== '/' ? `?${search.toString()}` : ''
      return <Redirect to={`/login${next}`} />
    }
  }
}
```

You need to update your reducer which handle `getLoggedInUserId` action to store also `isLoading` state.

Comment: I think this is a good direction. I'm actually looking for a customizable AuthRoute, where you could input (as params for the HOC): 1/ which state variable you're listening to (here `loggedInUserId`) and which function to call when that variable is not set (here `getLoggedInUserId()`)

Comment: @amaurymartiny that kind of logic could be handled in store itself. You’ve just described how react-apollo works and that’s built on top of redux. What about create ‘cacheFirst’ wrapper to your actions which only fires action when watched variable is null? You might need either redux-saga or redux-thunk for this functionality, but then your components are super simple.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want the initial state to be rendered by the server into 'index.html' (or what have you) and hydrated on the client.

This initial state would include `loggedInUserId` *and* data for the `/comments` page.

Check out https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.html

Comment: No, I'm looking for solutions for an SPA. I want `loggedInUserId` to be fetched at the beginning, and `state.comments` only on the `/comments` page after loggedInUserId has been fetched

Answer (score 2):

I think using HOC will be clean here. As all the common logic will be at the same place. Use composition here
Let say you have components A, B, C, D

Now you want to write some common function on the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle of all the components.

Write a HOC like:

```
class HOC extends React.Component {
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
//Your commomn logic
}
render() {
const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
 child => React.cloneElement(child, {
   ...this.props,
 })
 return (
  <div>
   {childrenWithProps}
  </div>
 )
}
}
```

Write your components like this:

```
class A extends React.Component {
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  //your uncommone logic
}
render(){
 return (
   <HOC {...this.props}>
    <div>
     //Your page jsx
    </div>
   </HOC>
 )
}
}
```

same way write for component B, C, and D. This pattern is useful when there is lot common among components. So better have a look at your usecase

Comment: What if the common logic is not that common? E.g. `/userId3/comments` would need to run beforehand `getUser(userId3)`, but `/postId4/comments` would need to run `getPost(post4)`? I.e. the fact that some async data is needed prior to `fetchComments` is common, but that prior data can be fetched differently?

Comment: Yeah that can also be accomodated with code setup that i mentioned . let me edit the answer. Please let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

OP writing. After reading nice ideas here, I decided to go with a custom HOC:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const requireProp = (As, propsSelector, propsToDispatch) =>
  class Wrapper extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      if (!propsSelector(this.props) && typeof propsToDispatch === 'function') {
        propsToDispatch(this.props);
      }
    }

    render() {
      const { ...props } = this.props;
      return !!propsSelector(this.props) && <As {...props} />;
    }
  };

export default requireProp;
```

To see how I use it, see [this gist](https://gist.github.com/amaurymartiny/9da446a06d4a785d7cf6921c27cd5636).

Comment: @Tomas Ehrlich: Mainly followed your idea, however I didn't see the need for redux-saga or redux-thunk.